# How can I detect the active textfield is touched again?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Textfield containes a data picker. And because picker has no `Return` button, I have to close `inputView` somehow. I do not want to use `inputAccessoryView` so I though **if user press again textfield should dismiss textfield**. But I do not know how detect touch event. I subclassed `UITextField` and overwritten `touchesBegan` method, but it never get called even dow if I set `userInteractionEnabled` to false.

I tried to set up a tap gesture recognizer, first it fires, but second times not.

```
class TextFieldCloseWhenTouched: UITextField {

    override func didMoveToWindow() {

        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped"))
    }

    func tapped() {
        if self.isFirstResponder() {
            self.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            self.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the delegate function `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` without subclassing textfield, but then you will need to handle adding and removing the picker to the view with animation yourself, not as input view.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  if(isTextFieldOpen){
     [self dismissDataPicker];
  }
  else{
     [self showDataPicker];
  }
  isTextFieldOpen=!isTextFieldOpen;

  return NO;

}
```

However, I don't think that this is the best user experience to make. I think it's better to either add the data picker to UIView with toolbar that has Done/Cancel button(s), or add a tap gesture recognizer to the main view when the data picker is shown so when the user tap anywhere it's dismissed.
If this is the only textfield in your screen, or you are okay to dismiss all by tapping anywhere, you can just add the following to your viewcontroller

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have  tableView behind keyboard so touchBegin does not work, but at the end I have used inputAccessoryView and put a Return button on it. I think I will be satisfied with that.